# Java 8 Map and Reduce doesnt run

Tags: lambda, java-8, java

I was using Project Lambdas' .map() method to extract some data from a List object. Before, Jdk 1.8 contained Mapper interface but now, I see that it map method gets Function interface. My method usage below:

```
 List<Nut> nutList =new ArrayList<Nut>();
```

I've added some items to nutList and im using below method to extract a fields value by getter.

```
nutList.stream().map(n->n.getShell())
```

But above n parameter behave like an Object and it doesn't access to original object's method. This usage was normally run with Mapper Functional interface.

Comment: that should work. what if you write `map(Nut::getShell)`

Comment: @LouisWasserman That's pure FUD (and quite wrong), no use at all to the poster. Why don't you address the question instead?

Answer (score 1):

Under b75, the following code compiles and runs correctly:

```
    List<Nut> nutList =new ArrayList<>();
    nutList.stream().map(n -> n.getShell()).forEach(System.out::print);
```

Perhaps you're using an older version?

Comment: Thanks, but i'm using b75 Maurice.

Comment: That's pretty odd then; the code I've posted compiles and runs for me. Check that out and if it still fails post the exact error message.